# Поиск по таблице с помощью RegExp Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таблица, в шапке которой расположены поля для поиска текста в столбце:

```
<table id="rez_tablh">
<tr>
<th id="thnaim"><input type="text" placeholder="Наименование..."></th>
<th id="thinv"><input type="text" placeholder="Номер № ..."></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

И таблица, в которую выводится результат выборки:

```
  table id="rez_tab">
  <tr>
  <td id="naim">Яблоко</td>
  <td id="inv">1234</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="naim">Яблоко</td>
  <td id="inv">23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="naim">Яблоко</td>
  <td id="inv">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="naim">Яблоко</td>
  <td id="inv">784</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="naim">Груша</td>
  <td id="inv">23</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Поиск по столбцам осуществляется так:

```
 $("#thnaim :input").bind("keyup", function() {

 var filter=$(this).val();  

 $('#rez_tab tr').find('#naim').each(function () {

 if(($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter,"i"))<0))
 {

    $(this).parent().hide();
 }
 else
 {
    $(this).parent().show();
 }

 });
 });

 $("#thinv :input").bind("keyup", function() {

 var filter=$(this).val();  

 $('#rez_tab tr').find('#inv').each(function () {

 if(($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter,"i"))<0))
 {

    $(this).parent().hide();
 }
 else
 {
    $(this).parent().show();
 }

 });
 });
```

Как можно реализовать совместное использование фильтров? Чтобы при поиске яблока с номером 23 отображалось только яблоко с номером 23. Сейчас же отображается и яблоко, и груша.

Пример работы: [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/azaza/uxtf8u4j/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать одну функцию обработки, в которой одновременно проверяются оба поля:

```js
$("#rez_tablh input").on("keyup", function(){
    var filterN = $("#thnaim input").val(),
        filterI = $("#thinv input").val();

    $("#rez_tab tr").each(function () {
        var n = $(this).find('#naim').text(),
            i = $(this).find('#inv').text();
        if (n.search(new RegExp(filterN,"i")) < 0 ||
            i.search(new RegExp(filterI,"i")) < 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="rez_tablh">
    <tr>
        <th id="thnaim"><input type="text" placeholder="Наименование..."></th>
        <th id="thinv"><input type="text" placeholder="Номер № ..."></th>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="rez_tab">
    <tr>
        <td id="naim">Яблоко</td>
        <td id="inv">1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="naim">Яблоко</td>
        <td id="inv">23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="naim">Яблоко</td>
        <td id="inv">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="naim">Яблоко</td>
        <td id="inv">784</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="naim">Груша</td>
        <td id="inv">23</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**P.S.** Если вам нужно по второму полю точное сравнение числа, то вместо регулярки используйте просто сранение значений или в регулярку добавьте символы начала и конца строки.

Comment: А как быть если нужен поиск по 5 столбцам?