# Результат живого поиска выводить только после ввода трёх символов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ответ **Visman** на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/553447/460426) отлично подходит для решения моей задачи, однако таблица с данными для фильтрации состоит из нескольких сотен строк и сильно загромождает страницу. Возможно ли изменить код так, чтобы при пустых полях ввода таблица всегда была скрыта, а вывод отфильтрованных данных начинался не ранее ввода трёх символов в строку поиска?

```
$("#rez_tablh input").on("keyup", function(){
    var filterN = $("#thnaim input").val(),
        filterI = $("#thinv input").val();

    $("#rez_tab tr").each(function () {
        var n = $(this).find('#naim').text(),
            i = $(this).find('#inv').text();
        if (n.search(new RegExp(filterN,"i")) < 0 ||
            i.search(new RegExp(filterI,"i")) < 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ну так проверьте длину вводимой строки, в чем сложность?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объяснение в комментариях к коду.

```js
$("#rez_tablh input").on("keyup", function() {
  var filterN = $("#thnaim input").val(),
      filterI = $("#thinv input").val();
  
  if(filterN.length >= 3  || filterI.length > 0) { // Если длина значения инпут #thnaim больше или равна 3, то выполняем функцию ниже
  // Если требуется аналогичное поведение у второго поля, то замените сравнение `filterI.length > 0` на `filterI.length >= 3`
    $("#rez_tab tr").each(function() {
      var n = $(this).find('#naim').text(),
          i = $(this).find('#inv').text();
      if(n.search(new RegExp(filterN, "i")) < 0 ||
        i.search(new RegExp(filterI, "i")) < 0) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  } else $("#rez_tab tr").show(); // Иначе показываем все варианты.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="rez_tablh">
  <tr>
    <th id="thnaim"><input type="text" placeholder="Наименование..."></th>
    <th id="thinv"><input type="text" placeholder="Номер № ..."></th>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="rez_tab">
  <tr>
    <td id="naim">Апельсин</td>
    <td id="inv">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="naim">Яблоко</td>
    <td id="inv">12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="naim">Апельсин</td>
    <td id="inv">42</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="naim">Груша</td>
    <td id="inv">312</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="naim">Яблоко</td>
    <td id="inv">23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Вариант с изначально скрытыми ячейками
**"Грубый" вариант**

```js
$("#rez_tablh input").on("keyup", function() {
  var filterN = $("#thnaim input").val(),
      filterI = $("#thinv input").val();
  
  if(filterN.length >= 3 || filterI.length > 0) {
    $("#rez_tab").show(); // Показываем таблицу #rez_tab, когда начинаем "поиск"
    $("#rez_tab tr").each(function() {
      var n = $(this).find('#naim').text(),
          i = $(this).find('#inv').text();
      if(n.search(new RegExp(filterN, "i")) < 0 ||
        i.search(new RegExp(filterI, "i")) < 0) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  } else {
    $("#rez_tab").hide(); // прячем таблицу
    $("#rez_tab tr").show();
  }
});
```

```css
#rez_tab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="rez_tablh">
  <tr>
    <th id="thnaim"><input type="text" placeholder="Наименование..."></th>
    <th id="thinv"><input type="text" placeholder="Номер № ..."></th>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="rez_tab">
  <tr>
    <td id="naim">Апельсин</td>
    <td id="inv">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="naim">Яблоко</td>
    <td id="inv">12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="naim">Апельсин</td>
    <td id="inv">42</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="naim">Груша</td>
    <td id="inv">312</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="naim">Яблоко</td>
    <td id="inv">23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, добрый человек, это то, что было нужно. А возможно, "чтобы при пустых полях ввода таблица всегда была скрыта"? Или для "живого поиска" это нереально?

Comment: Можно, сейчас допишу

Comment: Обратите внимание на первый код, я допустил ошибку - не учитывалось второе поле, пока заполнится, сейчас поправил.

Comment: Это ОТЛИЧНЫЙ вариант, а не "Грубый". Спасибо ещё раз.

Comment: "грубость" варианта заключается в том, что это пример к примеру, и не очень продуманный, такой - как вариант. В идеале под нужды вёрстку и нужды пишется код, в вашем случае, раз у вас много элементов для поиска, то ещё и оптимизированный под работу с большим кол-вом данных.